# Why onKeyPress doesn't work for me in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio, onkeypress

**I want to play the audio using ''onkeypress'' event:**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default ({ source }) => {
  const audRef = useRef(null);
  const onPlayHandler = () => {
    audRef.current.play();
    console.log("Key pressed.");
  };
  return (
    <div tabIndex="1" className="drum-pad" onKeyPress={onPlayHandler}>
      <audio ref={audRef} className="clip" controls>
        <source src={source} type="audio/mpeg" />
        <source src={source} type="audio/ogg" />
      </audio>
      W
    </div>
  );
};
```

But it doesn't work for me. 
**Note: It works only after clicking the tab button but I want to play on any keypress and without using inside input tag. full code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-gagarin-4ojec?file=/src/App.js) on codesandbox.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach event listener to div you want to capture. But your code does not look like that requirement. Better way is to add event listener on `dom` mounted. You can do something like this:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default ({ source }) => {
  const audRef = useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onPlayHandler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", onPlayHandler);
    };
  },[]);
  const onPlayHandler = () => {
    console.log("Key pressed.");
    audRef.current.play();
  };
  return (
    <div tabIndex="1" className="drum-pad">
      <audio ref={audRef} className="clip" controls>
        <source src={source} type="audio/mpeg" />
        <source src={source} type="audio/ogg" />
        <source src={source} type="audio/wav" />
      </audio>
      W
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-tdd-fe3e1?file=/src/DrumPad.js:0-672

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Try with `onKeyUp` instead of `onKeyPress`

Long answer: some keys fire some of these events and don't fire others. For instance,

- KeyPress ignores delete, arrows, PgUp/PgDn, home/end, ctrl, alt,
  shift etc while KeyDown and KeyUp don't (see details about esc
  below);
- when you switch window via alt+tab in Windows, only KeyDown for alt
  fires because window switching happens before any other event (and
  KeyDown for tab is prevented by system, I suppose, at least in Chrome
  71).